# How to access the menu items inside a navigation drawer - android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, navigation-drawer, android-espresso

Want to access the menu items inside a navigation drawer when testing using espresso.

I have tried the below code. onView(..).check(..) is fine.
The problem is with the opening the drawer from the `DrawerActions.open()`

```
@Test
public void testDrawer(){
    onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.drawer_layout)).perform(DrawerActions.open());
}
```

Error:

```
androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'open drawer with gravity 8388611' on view 'with id: io.apptizer.standalone:id/drawer_layout'.
```

I am getting this error, when trying above code sample